# Would using setTimeout in a serverless function cause any issue to me?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, vercel

Since the JavaScript main thread runs infinitely until all callstack goes empty, I am using `setTimeout` to create a session on demand and instead of sending expiration time, I am using setTimeout to pop the session after every N minutes.

Now I am deploying my backend in Node using serverless cloud functions (In Vercel, to be more specific). I wanted to know if it is advisable to use `setTimeout` since it will keep re-running main thread until the timeout completes and the callback executes in a serverless function or should I completely discard this approach?

Here's how my implementation looks like:

```
const ttl = 3600 * 1000;
const addSession = async (ua: string): Promise<string> => {
    const snapshot = await ref.push({ ua });
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (snapshot.key) ref.child(snapshot.key).remove();
    }, ttl);
    if (!snapshot.key) return addSession(ua);
    return snapshot.key;
}
```